# What is the order of the element $10 \in (\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z)^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $p \geq 23$ be a prime number such that the decimal expansion (base 10) of $\frac{1}{p}$ is periodic with period $p-1$ . Let $(\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z)^*$ denote the multiplicative group of integers modulo $p$. Then which of the following is true?

1) The order of the element $10 \in  (\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z)^*$ is a proper divisor of $p-1$.

2) The order of the element $10 \in  (\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z)^*$ is  $(p-1)/2$.

3) The element $10 \in  (\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z)^*$  is a generator of the group $(\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z)^*$

My Attempt : I know that the group $(\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z)^*$ is cyclic. And the prime number $p$ is a divisor of $10^{p-1} -1$. I can not deduce anything else from the given question. Can anyone please help me to proceed?

Comment: Well, $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$ being cyclic doesn't have anything to do with $10$, and $10^{p-1} - 1$ being divisible by $p$ is just Fermat's last theorem. There is a crucial piece of information you haven't used here, and that's the period of the decimal expansion of $\frac1p$. So the real task is therefore: can you find a connection between long division (in base $10$) and the order of $10$ modulo the denominator of that division? Try out $1\div23$, for instance, and see what happens. Can you see anything which looks like modulo 23 happening when you carry out that division by hand?

Comment: Can you please tell me what is long division?@Arthur

Comment: It's the standard algorithm you (hopefully) learned in elementary school to carry out division with pen and paper.

Comment: "the order of $10$ modulo the denominator of that division "  Can you please tell me what is the meaning of this line?@Arthur

Comment: Take the example of $p = 23$. See if you can find a connection between what happens when you carry out the division $1\div 23$, and the powers of $10$ modulo $23$.

Comment: I really can not understand your language. Can you please write an answer in short?@Arthur

Comment: (1) Do the division $1\div 23$ by hand. (2) Calculate the powers of $10$ modulo $23$. (3) Compare. Tell me which of those three is difficult to understand, and I'll help you out.

Comment: I can not understand (2). What is the powers of 10 modulo 23?@Arthur

Comment: The powers of $10$ are $10^1, 10^2, 10^3,$ and so on. The powers of $10$ modulo $23$ means you take all those numbers modulo $23$.

Comment: Now I can understand.@Arthur

Comment: Thank you@Arthur..By following your guidance I could solve the problem on my own and I learnt a lot of other things associated with this problem..

Comment: I didn't got the connection connection, can any one explains as an answer

Comment: @Arthur I am looking forward to see your neat way as an answer. Why don't you do that? I, myself, am learning new fresh things through the above comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Gathering my comments above into an answer: We calculate $1\div 23$ the way I learned to do division in elementary school and compare to calculating powers of $10$ modulo $23$.

I start with how many times $1$ goes into $23$. The answer is none, with a remainder of $1$. So to begin with, we write
$$
1\div 23=0
$$
Next, we move one decimal place over, and make our remainder of $1$ into $10$. So we ask how many times $23$ goes into $10$. Once again the answer is $0$, this time with a remainder of $10$. And we write
$$
1\div23=0.0
$$
Next, we move another decimal place over and make our remainder into $100$. Once again we ask how many times does $23$ go into $100$? The answer is $4$, with a remainder of $8$. We write
$$
1\div 23=0.04
$$
And so on. We make $8$ into $80$, divide, get $3$ with a remainder of $11$. Next we make $11$ into $110$, divide, get $4$ with a remainder of $18$. So far, this has given us $$1\div 23=0.00434$$and this just continues indefinitely.

Now compare with computing powers of $10$ modulo $23$. We get
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
n&10^n\bmod 23\\\hline
0&1\\
1&10\\
2&8\\
3&11\\
4&18\\
\vdots&\vdots
\end{array}
$$
Do you recognize these numbers? Can you see how they are actually connected? (Think about how you might calculate the right-hand column, and see if you can recognize the steps.) And from this, can you answer the actual problem?

Comment: Enjoy reading your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Now we have, $p$ is a prime $(\geq 23)$ and ${\mathbb{Z}_{p}}^{*}$ is a cyclic group with order $p-1$. Again by **Fermat's Little theorem**, $10^{p-1}\equiv 1 (\bmod \ p)$. So order of $10$ in group ${\mathbb{Z}_{p}}^{*}$ is $\leqslant p-1$. Suppose, $\circ (10) = m < p-1$$,$ then $10^{m}\equiv 1 (\bmod \ p)$. Since $p$ is a prime $(\geq 23)$, so $p\mid (1+10+\dots + 10^{m-1})$. Let $k$ be positive integer such that, $\frac{1}{p} = \frac{k}{1+10+\dots + 10^{m-1}}$. Now if $1\leq k< 10$, then $$\frac{k}{1+10+\dots + 10^{m-1}} = 0.\overline{\underset{\longleftarrow m-2 \longrightarrow}{00\dots 00}(k-1)(10-k)}.$$

Therefore, $\frac{1}{p}$ is periodic with period $m$, a big contradiction!. So option $(3)$ is the only correct option.